# Noise variance estimation

Tags: digital-communications, estimation, snr, analog-to-digital, channel

could anyone recommend some articles how to estimate noise variance for the single carriers system with burst mode transmission (preamble+data TDMA)?

My goal at the beginning is to develop skills how detect the preamble. I take the simplest case as a starting point, AWGN channel. I am going to use a BPSK preamble with good ACF. The modulation for the payload would be QPSK. So my first goal is to calculate the adaptive threshold so that I could detect the preamble at the output of the matched filter. To do that I need the noise variance

thanks.

Comment: That depends on what kind of modulation you use, which amount of your transmit energy is in your preamble, and how you model your channel, including the interference scenario (which might be easy or hard in TDMA systems) . You will want to specify these – otherwise the recommendations you get will be far more general than you probably expect them to be. For example, I'd refer you to a basic communications engineering textbook to discuss how preamble are used to estimate channels including the noise variance, and maybe Steven Kay: *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume I & II*.

Comment: Marcus, thanks for the book.

Comment: My goal at the beginning is to develop skills how detect the preamble. I take the simplest case as a starting point, AWGN channel. I am going to use a BPSK preamble with good ACF. The modulation for the payload would be QPSK. So my first goal is to calculate the adaptive threshold so that I could detect the preamble at the output of the matched filter. To do that I need the noise variance.

Comment: **edit** your question to include all that information, please!

Comment: As far as I understand from the intuitive point of view, the sigma^2 could be estimated by means of a known preamble at RX side. How could I do that (let's say that I already found  the packet boundary). Secondly, I still need to do the packet detection. The threshold calculation needs the knowledge of sigma.

Comment: I am not asking for the solution just point me to the articles or give the idea please. Thanks again for the M. Kay book.

Comment: well if you are sure you've detected a preamble, you can determine the correlation coefficient with the known preamble, giving you the energy of the preamble. Subtracting that energy from the received signal's power for the same samples would give you the energy in your received signal that's not from the preamble – and since there's nothing but preamble and noise, and noise is uncorrelated to the preamble, all that energy would be noise energy, directly giving you a variance estimate. The *actual* problems start because you cannot a priori say whether you actually detected the preamble.

Comment: But that's really just preamble detection. You would really want to consult a **basic** textbook on digital communications on that – things like false alarm rate will be good to know.